# SQL How to Update SUM of column over group in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have a (SQL Server) table similar to the following:

SalesSummary

Year  | Team | Person | Person Sales | Team Sales/Yr

2013      1             Jim                    $10                             ??

2013      1             Anna                 $0                             ??

2013      2             John                  $8                              ??

2013      3            Todd                   $4                              ??

2013      3            Alan                    $1                              ??

2014      3            Alan                  $22                            ??

I'm trying to sum over this example SalesSummary table and insert the proper values into the Team Sales column. In this example, I would want $10 in the 1st and 2nd columns, $8 in the 3rd, $5 in the 4th/5th and $22 in the 6th column slot. Forgive my ignorance of SQL, but I settled on what I'm told is a poor solution as follows:

```
UPDATE SalesSummary SET TeamSales = sum.TeamSales
FROM (SELECT Team, Year, SUM(PersonSales) OVER (Partition By Team, Year) as TeamSales)
      FROM SalesSummary
      GROUP BY Team, Year, PersonSales
     ) AS sum, SalesSummary as SS
WHERE sum.Team = ss.Team AND sum.Year = ss.Year
```

I was hoping someone might be able to show be how best to perform this type of update. I appreciate any help, tips, or examples. Apologies if this is obvious.

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server. Apologies for the miss.

Comment: BTW, creating of such column is totally unnecessary. Why do you need this column if you can always calculate the value using the SQL syntax you have provided?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, I think you want something like this:

```
WITH toupdate AS
     (SELECT team, year, 
             Sum(personsales) OVER (partition BY team, year) AS newTeamSales 
      FROM salessummary
     ) 
UPDATE toupdate 
   SET teamsales = newteamsales;
```

Your original query has several issues and suspicious constructs.  First, an aggregation subquery is not updatable.  Second, you are doing an aggregation and using a window function with, although allowed, is unusual.  Third, you are aggregating by `PersonSales` and taking the `sum()`.  Once again, allowed, but unusual.

Answer (score 9):

Try this.

```
UPDATE  SalesSummary SET TeamSales = (Select Sum(PersonSales) 
        From    SalesSummary S 
        Where S.Year=SalesSummary.Year AND S.Team=SalesSummary.Team)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a table variable instead a regular table, therefore I needed to adapt @Shell's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21871500/593045) a bit - so my solution for the question's problem when the table is a variable:

```
Update SU
Set TeamSales = (Select Sum(SI.PersonSales) 
                 From   @SalesSummary SI 
                 Where  SI.Year=SU.Year AND SI.Team=SU.Team)
From @SalesSummary SU
```